# nginx and index.php downloading

Tags: php, nginx, php-7.1

I just installed Nginx with PHP 7.1-fpm on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have a problem. When I wan to visit for example http://example.dev it downloads 
index.php instead of showing homepage, but for example http://example.dev/registration works well.

This is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example/www;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name example.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Try moving `    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }` to the end

Comment: have you set 'cgi.fix_pathinfo' in php.ini file ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried it but it didn't help.

Comment: @AshishTiwari Yes

Comment: Does `http://example.dev` and `http://example.dev/` both result in download of `index.php` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it can be as simple as clearing the browser cache. If there was some misconfiguration and it was indeed downloading files, after fixing the config the browser needs to be told to stop using the cached download.

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in your browser.

(From: https://askubuntu.com/questions/460710/why-is-the-index-php-downloaded-instead-of-rendered-by-nginx)